# What makes this construction?

Tags: c

What makes this construction?

```
int a[10];
int x;
x = 2[a];
```

I do not understand what makes 2 [a]. It is another senility of C language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is

`2[a] = *(2 + a) = *(a + 2) = a[2]`

Note: `+` operator holds commutative property

Answer (score 3):

Array subscripting is commutative in C. `a[2]` and `2[a]` and `*(a + 2)` are equivalent, i.e. the compiler produces the same code. There is a [C FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html) for it.